# View remote Tomcat logs in Eclipse Console

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I am experimenting with a combination of Vagrant+VirtualBox+JRebel+Eclipse+Tomcat to develop a Java Servlet application. My Tomcat instance runs in a VirtualBox VM, which for Eclipse purposes means it is a remote server. I was able to get hot deploying (JRebel) and debug mode working.

I haven't yet found a good way to get the logs to show up in Eclipse, though. Ideally, I'd like something very similar to the Console view that Eclipse/WTP gives for local Tomcat instances. Some features I like:

- Lines in stack traces are clickable, taking me right to the source file
- Easily searchable
- Highlighting (errors show up in red)
- Shows up right in my IDE
- Can be cleared when I'm sick of seeing too much

The first two features (clickable and searchable) are the most important to me. Does anyone know of a plugin or separate app that can accomplish this?

[LogViewer](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/logviewer) appears to be abandoned (and possibly non-functional in current Eclipse versions), and [JLV](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/jlv) doesn't appear to have clickable source lines.

Answer (score 0):

[NTail](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ntail) might do the job. It hasn't been updated since 2010, but it seems to work on Eclipse Luna.